# Flip Normal of Plane

Tags: vectors

Hi If I have a general form of a plane such as : $2x + 4y - 6z + 10 = 0$

what is the method for inverting the normal vector?? I realize the normal vector for this equation is $(2, 4, -6)$

would the flip be  $(-2, -4, 6)$ perhaps?

thanks

Comment: To judge your own answer it is necessary to know what "inverting a vector" stands for in your context. So add that to your question.

Comment: Yes negating a vector is "flipping" it, i.e. going along the same line, but pointing backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes negating a vector is "flipping" it, i.e. going along the same line, but pointing backwards.

You can see this because all the vectors on the "vector line" spanned by a vector $v$ have the form $k \cdot v$, for $k \in \mathbb{R}$.  If $k > 0$, you just have a larger or bigger vector, and if $k < 0$ you moreover flipped it.

You can get the feeling why that's true that another way.  Obviously $(1,0,0)$ flips to $(-1,0,0)$ and so on for $(0,1,0)$ to $(0,-1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,0,-1)$.  But a vector $(a,b,c)$ can be written
$$
a\cdot(1,0,0) + b\cdot(0,1,0) + c\cdot(0,0,1).
$$
Thus by flipping, we have
$$
a\cdot(-1,0,0) + b\cdot(0,-1,0) + c\cdot(0,0,-1),
$$
which is equal to
$$
(-a,-b,-c) = -(a,b,c).
$$